# Use the standard output as stream

Tags: powershell, stream, stdout

Some .Net method I want to use ([XslCompiledTransform.transform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163438(v=vs.110).aspx)) accepts a TextWriter for its output.
How do I specify the standard output?

```
$Xsl.Transform($XMLInputPath, $nul, ¿standard output?)
                                    -----------------
```

Comment: I want the (characters) result of the transformation output on the console (or to a file if redirected).

Comment: OK. `[Console]::Out` sort of works.

Comment: You should post an answer. `[Console]::Out` works if I run `powershell script.ps1 > output.txt` from cmd. Redirection does not work from within PowerShell. And there seem to be no output when running script within the ISE. Do you have an explanation / a pointer?